# Is $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ a Banach Space?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, banach-spaces

By defining $$
C_0(\mathbb{R}^n):=\{u:u\in C(\mathbb{R}^n),\quad\mathtt{and}\quad\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}u(x)=0\}
$$
normed with $||u||:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|u(x)|$. As far as I can remember, this is a Banach space.

My question:
Is this ture or there are counterexamples for this?

Attempts:
I think it is easy to give counterexaple for $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where the condition of "limit at infinitty" is changed into "having compact support". In fact by considering $$
f_n(x):=f_{n-1}(x)+\dfrac{1}{n} \chi_{x\in B_n\setminus B_{n-1}},\quad f_0(x):=0,\ B_0:=\varnothing.
$$
which  is a Cauchy sequence in $C_c$ but the limit doesn't have compact support. But the limit satisfies $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$.

Thanks for reading and any idea will be helpful.

Comment: I believe $C_0(X)$ is Banach for any locally compact $X$. I believe it is even a $C^*$-algebra, only not necessarily unital.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I remembered where to find a proof of this in my textbook. $C_0(X)$ is just the pre-dual space of Radon Measure space and it is the closure of $C_c(X)$ under this norm. Really appreciate the kindness hit. ;)

Comment: @Zixiao_Liu Don 't ignore absolute value signs. Your $\|u\|$ is not a norm.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the absolute value signs. So sorry about that. I will restate the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is isometric to the space $\mathbb{E}$ of continuous functions on $S^n$ (one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$) which vanish on $\infty$. The latter is the kernel under the evaluation map 
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{ev}_{\infty}:C(S^n) &\to \mathbb{R}\\
f &\mapsto f(\infty).
\end{align*}
Since the evaluation map is continuous, $\mathbb{E}$ is closed, therefore Banach (since $C(S^n)$ is Banach) and it follows that $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ also is.

As was said in the comments, this holds for any locally compact space Hausdorff $X$ in place of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The proof is the same.